# Merge multiple dataframes outputted via a FOR loop function into one single dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a FOR loop function that iterates over a list of tables and columns (zip) to get minimum and maximum values. The output is separated for each of the combination rather than one single dataframe/table. Is there a way to combine the results of FOR loop into one final output within the function?

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

def minmax(tables, cols):
    for table, column in zip(tables, cols):
        minmax = spark.table(table).where(col(column).isNotNull()).select(f.lit(table).alias("table"), f.lit(column).alias("col"), min(col(column)).alias("min"), 
        max(col(column)).alias("max"))
        minmax.show()
```

```
tables = ["sales_123", "sales_REW"]
cols = ["costs", "price"]

minmax(tables, cols)
```

Output from the function:

```
+---------+-----+---+---+
|    table|  col|min|max|
+---------+-----+---+---+
|sales_123|costs|  0|400|
+---------+-----+---+---+

+----------+-----+---+---+
|     table|  col|min|max|
+----------+-----+---+---+
|sales_REW |price|  0|400|
+----------+-----+---+---+
```

Desired Output:

```
+---------+-----+---+---+
|    table|  col|min|max|
+---------+-----+---+---+
|sales_123|costs|  0|400|
|sales_REW|price|  0|400|
+---------+-----+---+---+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put all the dataframes into a list and do the union after the for-loop:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def minmax(tables, cols):

    dfs = []        
    for table, column in zip(tables, cols):
        minmax = spark.table(table).where(col(column).isNotNull()).select(f.lit(table).alias("table"), f.lit(column).alias("col"), min(col(column)).alias("min"), max(col(column)).alias("max"))
        dfs.append(minmax)
    df = reduce(DataFrame.union, dfs)
```

Note that the order of the columns needs to be the same of all involved dataframes (as is the case here). Otherwise this can have unexpected results.

Comment: @Shaido How can i prepare the table and columns to test the code ?

Comment: @PIG: If you just want to test it you can simply create a list of Spark dataframes (read from csvs, or create some from pandas dataframes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751509/how-to-create-new-dataframe-with-dict) and then loop over those.

Comment: @Shaido I am trying to pass `minmax(df1, cols)` where df1 is my spark dataframe & cols = df1.columns, its says column not iterable

Comment: @Abhi: If you only have a single dataframe then you shouldn't use the solution above. However, what you want to do will differ a lot depending on what you actually want to do, maybe something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534796/pyspark-how-to-iterate-over-dataframe-columns-and-change-data-type or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382329/pyspark-python-iterate-through-dataframe-columns-check-for-a-condition-and-popu

Comment: @Shaido Yes! Simply ran `df.select(*[f.mean(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns])`. Can you help with percentile, I have a ID (unique) column, category (5 distinct values) column, 5 numeric columns. Percentile - 25%, 50%, 75%, 100% required for each numeric column. Will run loop for the 5 categories